# How to initialize tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable used in Tensorflow Estimator model_fn?

Tags: tensorflow, lookup-tables, tensorflow-estimator

I have a `tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable` declared inside a **Tensorflow Estimator model_fn**. As the session is not directly available to us in Estimators, I am stuck with not being able to initialize the table. I am aware that if not used with Estimators, table can be initialized with `table.init.run()` using the session

I tried to initialize the table by using a `sessionRunHook` which I was already using for some other purpose. I pass the table init op as argument to session run in the `before_run` function. But table is still not initialized. I also tried to pass `tf.tables_initializer()` instead, but that did not work too. Another option I tried  without success is the `tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS.. command.`

```
#sessionRunHook code below

class SaveToCSVHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    def begin(self):        
        samples_weights_table = session.graph.get_tensor_by_name('samples_weights_table:0')
        self.samples_weights_table_init_op = samples_weights_table.init
        self.table_init_op = tf.tables_initializer() # also tried passing this to self.args instead - same result though
        tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS, samples_weights_table.init)

    def after_create_session(self, session, coord):
        self.args ={'table_init_op':self.samples_weights_table_init_op}

    def before_run(self, run_context):
         return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(self.args)

    def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
        print(f"Got Values: {run_values.results}")  

# Estimator model_fn code below

def model_fn(..)
    samples_weights_table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keysb, values, key_dtype=tf.string, value_dtype=tf.float32,name='samples_weights_table_init_op'), -1.0,name='samples_weights_table')
```

I get error:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Table not initialized

which obviously means the table is not getting initialized

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested to know the answer, the hashtable need not be explicitly initialized when used with Estimators. They are initialized by default for high level APIs like Estimators. The error goes away when the initializer code is removed and the table works as expected.